# Project management software that allows to juggle meetings, recurring tasks and projects

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for a project management software that allows to manage efficiently meetings, recurring tasks and projects.

I would like the software to say to me when I can insert a new project without impacting in actual deadlines. Or when is the best date to start a new project.

I would like to manage efficiently meetings (events that last only 2 hours, one specific day).

I would like to know if I'm going to finnish a project before the deadline with the current state of the tasks.

Comment: Any requirements of OS &/or Price Range, On/Off-line, allowing others to see your schedule!

Comment: Windows or Linux would be ok. For price Range, On/Off-line or allowing others to see my schedule I have no specific requirements.

Comment: I hope [my answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/17187/8094) reflects this question.

Comment: @0x54MUR41 you do not say anything answering this question just recommend other project management software. Please, answer if Producteev implements what this question asks for.