# A todo app that allows specifying task duration and more

Tags: gratis, project-management

I want a todo app that allows me to specify these things for each task:

- an estimate of how long the task will take
- any dependencies, i.e. other tasks
- the reason for doing the app, i.e. reward
- due date
- priority
- category

I also want to be able to sort tasks by either:

- created time
- due date
- priority
- category

Is there anything with most of these features which is free and available on web and mobile?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you this one, **[Producteev](https://www.producteev.com)** by [Jive](https://www.jivesoftware.com).

> Producteev is *task management software*. 
>   Get the things done wherever you go with the world's best task manager app. The
>   application is simple, power full, and more than an online to-do list. It's helped hundreds of thousands of teams work faster with better results

The main object concern of this apps is the team (*I am so sorry if I missed that you have mentioned the task management for yourself*), but you can start the application first for yourself.

OK. There below are the **features** of **Producteev** which at least meets your requirements:

1. **Networks**: A network is your company's workplace on [Producteev](https://www.producteev.com). It includes all your projects, tasks and collaborators in one convenient and easy-to-use interface.
2. **Tasks**: A task is your to-do item. It can be assigned, labeled, prioritized, tracked, commented on, and even set as a recurring reminder.
3. **Labels**: A label allows you to categorize tasks with a custom description and color.
4. **Priorities**: Setting a priority allows you to rank your tasks according to their importance.
5. **Subtasks**: Subtasks can be added within tasks to create a simple checklist that can be reordered, checked off or deleted.
6. **Deadlines**: Setting a due date within a task allows you to schedule deadlines and even sort by due date if you like.
7. *more...*

The features above are taken from [here](https://www.producteev.com/features), I don't mention all of them. Ahh.. I remember, this application are **free** (you can compare the [plan](https://www.producteev.com/pricing) too) and you can use through the **web** or **mobile phone**.

Comment: This is discontinued now

Answer (score 1):

I use Abstract Spoon's [ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html). It supports prerequisites and is also available Android & iOS. I generally use it from planning s/w projects, but ocassioanlly just for day to day ToDo stuff.

```
ToDoList's flexible design makes it ideal for both IT related projects  
as well as more general GTD uses.
```

Check out a video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv7ARrRTUhI

Download it from [here](http://abstractspoon.pbwiki.com/f/todolist_exe.zip).

[image]

Comment: This looks promising.  Does it have native sync to mobile, or is that accomplished by external services like Dropbox, SpiderOak, SyncThing, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like ToDoList and want something a bit more like MS Project, there are, of course, several (sucha s https://www.openproject.org/ which might be too much for your needs).

The best that I found when I tried them all a few months ago (before deciding to stick with ToDoList), was [TaskJuggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/).

That one uses Gantt charts and has some impressive features:

Basic Properties

```
Manages tasks, resources and accounts of your project
Powerful to-do list management
Detailed reference manual
Simple installation
Runs on all Linux, Unix, Windows, MacOS and several other operating systems
Full integration with Vim text editor
```

Advanced Scheduling

```
Automatic resource leveling and tasks conflict resolution
Unlimited number of scenarios (baselines) of the same project for what-if analysis
Flexible working hours and leave management
Support for shift working
Multiple time zone support
```

Accounting

```
Tasks may have initial costs, finishing costs
Resources may have usage based costs
Task and/or resource base cost models
Support for profit/loss analysis
```

Reporting

```
Comprehensive and flexible reports so you can find the information you need when you need it
Powerful filtering functions to provide the right amount of detail to the right audience
Time and status sheet reporting infrastructure
Project tracking and status reporting with dashboard support
```